# Find hostname of device on local network with PHP

Tags: php, lan, hostname

I'm trying to determine the hostname of devices on the network to store to show more human information to my users as my source file unfortunately doesn't contain this (and is dynamic so I need to maintain this info elsewhere), however the built in PHP function gethostbyaddr() doesn't work.

For example, I have a device at `10.0.60.1` with hostname `Phone-Chris` (I don't care about the domain portion, just the hostname itself).

When I use:

```
<?php
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr("10.0.60.1");
    echo "$hostname";
?>
```

It just returns the IP address (which indicates that the lookup failed). If I change it to `8.8.8.8`, it works as expected and show `google-public-dns-a.google.com`. I get the impression this function probably won't do what I want as it seems to rely on reverse lookups.

How can I determine what the hosename is of a device on the network so that I can store that information in this manner? (i.e., return `Phone-Chris`).

Comment: Do you have a DNS server running on the local network? If not, I'm not sure where you expected this information to come from.

Comment: There is a DNS server on this network, however I can't use it to navigate to the device with the URL (even though the device has the same DNS server as me set and has a hostname applied). Is there perhaps a different way I can find this information?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with reverse dns lookups... you aren't going to get any love on this one from php for the masses. Only situation where is would work that I can tell is one where the client and the webserver share the same dns server.

Comment: In this case both the device I am querying and my machine (which is also the server), share the same DNS server. Even then I am unable to get this information though.

Comment: Do you have a reverse DNS `PTR` record in there?

Comment: try it with your [public ip address](http://www.whatsmyip.org/)... you probably will get something back although I don't think it's going to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Public is useless, I need to query a bunch of devices on the LAN and get their hostnames to log in an interface I am working on. Not sure how to do this now. Blast!

Comment: comamnd line: sudo arp -a